# OmniGraffle: change characters spacing for text to occupy surrounding rectangle how?

Tags: omnigraffle

Is there a simple command in OmniGraffle 6.0 x for **(a)** stretching the character spaces or **(b)** increasing font size of a word inside a rectangle (enlarge their distances) such that the word fills the entire rectangle nicely?

I would like to achieve an effect of the following kind: a square split into equal upper and lower rectangles; shorter word (e.g. "one") in upper, longer word (e.g. "four") in lower rectangle; words should align at their left and right margins and character spacings and/or font sizes should should remain even.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about OmniGraffle 6.x, but in the most recent version (7.18.5 at the time of this writing), you can accomplish this, although it's not quite as automatic as it could be.

If I'm interpreting the split square you describe above correctly and if we make it 100 px × 100 px, it should look something like this:

[image]

Select the top rectangle and, in the **Font** and **Text Position** inspectors, change the settings as follows:

[image]

Select the bottom rectangle and do the same, except change 21 to 13.

Those changes will get you this:

[image]

The most important points here are:

1. Uncheck **Auto-Kern** (kerning = space between letters).
2. Increase the kerning until the text goes where you want it to. Kerning of 21 and 13, respectively, worked for the two rectangles in this case.
3. Change the other settings to fill the space. Kerning in OmniGraffle increases the space *after* each character, and the other settings serve to make sure it fills the entire space without breaking, etc.

To make this scalable (or as scalable as you can get it), select the rectangles and, in the **Geometry** selector, select **Scale Font** or **Scale Stoke and Font** (if you also want to scale the stroke):

[image]

Unfortunately kerning does not scale with this, so you'll need to adjust the kerning manually each time you scale. For example, in the 80 px × 80 px scaled-down version in the image below, I had to reduce kerning in the rectangles to 17 and 10, respectively.

[image]